# php - A website works in server , same code downloded and tried to run using xampp its not working

Tags: php

Recently I have joined to a company. They given me task of maintaining the website and to add new features to existing website. This site is developed 3 yrs back.Developed using Php and sql as backend. I am new to php and tried to execute the site locally so that i can edit locally. So i have downloaded the entire folder located in hostgators public_html folder and also mysql data. Put up the entire content of public_html folder contents in htdocs folder and restored database. I am using xampp. As development tool i am using Dreamweaver cs3. I tried to run the index.php page (which is the first page to be called to run). I throws error saying 'fatal error :  undefined function getonfielddata ()'. I have searched entire files in htdocs folder for this function. Did not get. My question is that, Is there any location when we can keep function Hidden? 2). Is getonfielddata () built in function?. I am using xampp 3.2.1. 3) Is there any way to find definition of this missed function?

Comment: Code downloaded from public_html folder in hostgator

Comment: Sorry but you're going to need to provide way more information such as the process you have done to migrate the site from server to local and include specific narrowed down access/errors logs etc.

Comment: OK Sir, Let me explain it in more detail.

Comment: They gave me hostgator control panel ID and Password. I have logged in to cpanel, moved to File manager in that ziped public_html  Folder, and downloaded to my computer.

Comment: Then installed Dreamweaver cs 3 and XAMPP. Restored MySql database, which is downloaded from hostgator. Then tried to run this copied website using localhost. when I run the website using localhost, it gives error 'Fatal error: Call to undefined function findsettingvalue() ' . I have searched in entire public_html folder files for this function. Did not found. But the website in the cloud server works fine. My question is that i copied same code of cloud website, y it shows me error missing function when i run using xampp?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the additional information in an easy to read presentable way, and then a moderator will review your question.

Comment: Even after your edits this question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines. It its current form, this question does *not* meet their guidelines.